# Debugging a .NET COM DLL loaded by unmanaged C++ binary in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, interop

I'm using VS2010. I have an unmanaged EXE written in C++ that's using a .NET COM component which is also part of the same solution. I know that the COM object was created successfully because CoCreateInstance returned without an error. Yet, the component symbols aren't loaded (I can also notice that by not being able to create breakpoints in the .NET project source files), so I can't step into the code of the object's methods.

I tried to copy the .NET DLL's PDB into the same output directory of the EXE and it also didn't help. All projects in the solution are x64 and Debugging mode is set to Mixed.

If that matters, the DLL was registered using the command regasm /codebase

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to enable managed debugging.  One problem with Visual Studio (at least 2008 and 2010 -- don't know about later versions) is that you can only debug Native and Managed code at the same time with 32-bit processes.  With 64-bit processes, you have to debug one type or the other, but not both at the same time.  I suppose you might be able to spin up another instance of Visual Studio and debug the Native with one instance and Managed with the other.

Under your project settings, go to the "Configuration Properties" - "Debugging" page. On the right go over to Debugger Type and select Mixed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original post, the debugger type was already set to Mixed. The problem was with x64, as you suggested. Regarding your suggestion, I can't attach 2 VS debuggers to the same process, but when I want to debug x64-specific functionality I'll debug alternately in managed and native modes.